# How to add TinyPNG to Ckeditor & Elfinder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ckeditor, elfinder

i have a `laravel 5` project.

i use `Ckeditor` and `Elfinder` to upload images in my posts.

Normally , i use `TinyPng` php api to optimize my other images. But i can't integrate `TinyPng` api to `ckeditor&elfinder` .

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to install [laravel-image-optimizer](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-image-optimizer) by Spatie, basically it sets up a middleware which detects when the request contains an image and it passes the correct image optimizers you have installed in your system automatically.

To install it run:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-image-optimizer
```

And add to your config file `app.php`:

```
// config/app.php
'providers' => [
    ...
    Spatie\LaravelImageOptimizer\ImageOptimizerServiceProvider::class,
];
```

And:

```
// config/app.php
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'ImageOptimizer' => Spatie\LaravelImageOptimizer\ImageOptimizerFacade::class,
];
```

To use it wrap the upload endpoint with the middleware:

```
Route::middleware('optimizeImages')->group(function () {
    // all images will be optimized automatically
    Route::post('upload-images', 'UploadController@index);
});
```

As mentioned in the documentation the supported optimizers **by default** are:

> The package will use these optimizers if they are present on your
>   system:
>
> - JpegOptim
> - Optipng
> - Pngquant 2
> - SVGO
> - Gifsicle

If you want, by all means, to use your optimizer, this package has you covered, just follow [this section](https://github.com/spatie/image-optimizer#creating-your-own-optimization-chains) of the documentation.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it looks cool , i will try it. I am also happy with TinyPng compression power. But i could not find a way to use it with ckeditor :/

Comment: @YalınSemer I have never use that optimizer but the ones supported by the package are very good and recommended by multiple authorities like Google

Comment: @YalınSemer I have updated the answer with further information about adding your custom optimizer

Comment: actually this package is for laravel 5.4 and i can't use it with laravel 5.2

Comment: In my `config/elfinder.app`, I just use this in the Route group config array: `'middleware' => 'optimizeImages', 'web',  //Set to null to disable middleware filter`